# Fixed-pitch font encoding that includes DEC/Microsoft/IBM PC line-drawing characters

Tags: diagrams, characters

Is there a LaTeX fixed-pitch font encoding that includes the DEC line-drawing characters (that Microsoft and IBM included in early PCs)?

In X-windows, these are displayed using "dec" in the "registry" field in, for example, xfontsel. The line-drawing characters occupied what in ASCII would be lower-case letters' positions.

[image]

Comment: The Box Drawing glyphs (128 characters) are in Unicode, so in, for example, Noto Sans Mono font. Do you need to go from old code to box drawing (typing `c` produced `╔` or whatever)? A mapping file or regex-replace function could handle that.

Comment: Found the code table: https://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/chapter2.html#T2-4  "DEC Special Graphics Character Set"